# Continuity of the involution in Banach *-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

My question is concerned with the involution in Banach *-algebras.

**1- Should  the involution be assumed continuous in every Banach *-algebra?**

If the answer is negative,

**2- Does there exist any characterization of Banach *-algebras whose involution is continuous (isometry)?!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 1), this is § 36 (pp. 190) of Bonsall & Duncan:  The following are equivalent for a Banach *-algebra $A$, and the set $\text{Sym}(A')$ of all continuous self-adjoint linear functionals on $A$

- The linear involution $f \mapsto f^*$ is continuous on $A$
- $\text{Sym}(A')$ is separating on $A$
- $\text{Sym}(A)$ is closed on $A$